# how to navigate about Java POI sheet?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have an example of accessing a cell in a Java POI worksheet:

```
CellReference cr = new CellReference("A1");
row = mySheet.getRow(cr.getRow());
cell = row.getCell(cr.getCol());
```

but now if I need the next cell in a row or another cell in another row, is there an easy way to navigate about the worksheet? Is there some type of increment function?

Answer (score 0):

There should be an iterator of some sort. In an older version of POI it was something like this:
        Iterator rowIterator = sheet.rowIterator();
        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row R = rowIterator.next();
            Cell cell = R.getCell(1);
        }

Answer (score 0):

In the Javadoc of [HSSFRow](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFRow.html#cellIterator%28%29) there is an iterator() function however it is for *the physically defined cells*.

Answer (score 0):

cr.getRow() and cr.getCol() are int so they can be incremented to return the necessary cell